# update com auto relacionamento

Tags: sql

Tenho uma tabela chamada Categoria, nela tenho os atributos `ID, DESCRICAO e ORIGEM`, precisei incluir mais um atributo `ID_CATEGORIA_PAI`, esse atributo é um autorelacionamento com a mesma tabela. Agora preciso pegar algumas tuplas dessa tabela e informar o ID da categoria pai, as categorias filhas cadastradas hoje em dia possuem a mesma descrição da categoria pai, porem com a terminação ".1", ".2" e assim por diante e com a origem "filho".
Hoje está assim:

> ```
> CAT_ID | CAT_DESC       | CAT_ORIGEM | CAT_ID_PAI
> 1      | Categoria A    | Cadastro   | null
> 2      | Categoria B    | Cadastro   | null
> 3      | Categoria C    | Cadastro   | null
> 4      | Categoria A.1  | Filho      | null
> 5      | Categoria B.1  | Filho      | null
> 6      | Categoria C.1  | Filho      | null
> 7      | Categoria A.2  | Filho      | null
> 8      | Categoria B.2  | Filho      | null
> 9      | Categoria C.2  | Filho      | null
> ```

Preciso obter o seguinte resultado:

> ```
> CAT_ID | CAT_DESC       | CAT_ORIGEM | CAT_ID_PAI
> 1      | Categoria A    | Cadastro   | null
> 2      | Categoria B    | Cadastro   | null
> 3      | Categoria C    | Cadastro   | null
> 4      | Categoria A.1  | Filho      | 1
> 5      | Categoria B.1  | Filho      | 2
> 6      | Categoria C.1  | Filho      | 3
> 7      | Categoria A.2  | Filho      | 1
> 8      | Categoria B.2  | Filho      | 2
> 9      | Categoria C.2  | Filho      | 3
> ```

Alguém sabe me dizer se é possível fazer um script de update para atualizar essas categorias filhas tomando por base a descrição da categoria e a origem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Sim, é possível!* Considerando o exemplo de saída esperado, você precisa validar se o item que será atualizado (`CAT_ORIGEM`) é do tipo *"Filho"* e se existe um do tipo *"Cadastro"* que seja seu início, tipo assim:

```
UPDATE cadastro c
SET CAT_ID_PAI = (SELECT c2.CAT_ID 
                  FROM cadastro c2 
                  WHERE c.CAT_DESC LIKE CONCAT(c2.CAT_DESC, '%')
                    AND c2.CAT_ORIGEM = 'Cadastro'
                  LIMIT 1)
WHERE c.CAT_ORIGEM = 'Filho'
```

---

Como não especificou o banco, criei [este exemplo](https://rextester.com/TLS24010) em <kbd>mysql</kbd>; a query fica um pouco diferente pois usei um `join`, mas a ideia segue a mesma:

```
UPDATE categoria c
JOIN categoria c2 on c.CAT_DESC LIKE CONCAT(c2.CAT_DESC, '%')
SET c.CAT_ID_PAI = c2.CAT_ID
WHERE c.CAT_ORIGEM = 'Filho';
```